# Conditionally send data to multiple writers in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have some logic in my processor And based on that I need to decide if I need to write items in TableA (WriterA)  or TableB(writer)

e.g `Item` has filed `type` and type can have value as `A or B` and based on value in `type` filed I need to decide in which table I need to write the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `Classifier`. Below are the configurations:

**Writer** - Writer will set the `Classifer` to decide which writer we need to use. Based on classfiter output writer will be decided.

```
@Bean
public ItemWriter<Pojo> itemWriter() {
    BackToBackPatternClassifier classifier = new BackToBackPatternClassifier();
    classifier.setRouterDelegate(new MyClassifier());
    classifier.setMatcherMap(new HashMap<String, ItemWriter<? extends Pojo>>() {
        {
            put("A", WriterA);
            put("B", WriterB);

        }
    });
    ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Pojo> writer = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Pojo>();
    writer.setClassifier(classifier);
    return writer;      
}
```

**Classifier**

```
public class MyClassifier {

    @Classifier
    public String classify(Pojo Pojo) {
        return Pojo.getType();
    }
}
```